# React JSX <option> tag population

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to populate an options tag with string values from an array with the following function:

```
render: function(){
  var array = ['yes','no'];
  var opts = array.map(function(name){return <option>name</option>});
    return(
    <div>
      <select>{opts}</select>
    </div>
      );
 }
```

The problem is that I receive

```
<option>name</option>
<option>name</option>
```

But I need

```
<option>yes</option>
<option>no</option>
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `name` into `{}`

```js
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var array = ['yes','no'];
    var opts  = array.map(function(name){
      return <option>{ name }</option>
    });
    
    return <div>
      <select>{opts}</select>
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```